# PHP's Iterator class

Tags: php, iterator, spl

I am working with PHP's SPL Recursive Iterators, they are rather confusing to me though but I am learning.

I am using them in a project where I need to recursively grab all files and exclude folders from my result.  I was initially using this method...

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory,
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {    
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        //skip directories
        //continue;
    }else{
        // process files
    }
}
```

But then a SO user suggested that I use this method instead so that I would not need to use the `isDir()` method in my loop...

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,
                        RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory,
                        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);
```

Notice that I used `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` in the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` constructor which is supposed to skip folders or `.` and `..`

Now I am confused because after some test, even without using the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` it seems to not show them, I am using Windows could that be the reason, do the dots only show up on a Unix type system?  Or am I confused to the point that I am missing something?

Also by using `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` instead of `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST` it will stop folders from showing up in my result which is what I want but I don't understand why?  The documentation has no information on this

Comment: *(sidenote)* the default iteration mode is `LEAVES_ONLY`, so all you need to do is `new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);` - i will expand the docs for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leaf is an item in the *tree* which does not have any further items hanging off of it, i.e. it's the end of a branch. By definition, files fit this description.

```
-- folder
   |
   |- folder
   |  |
   |  |- file       <- a leaf
   |  |
   |  -- folder
   |     |
   |     -- file    <- another leaf
   |
   -- file          <- yet another leaf
```

By setting the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to "leaf only" mode, it's going to skip over any item that's not a leaf.

Comment: awesome answer does this mean that `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` is not needed when using leaf mode?

Comment: I would think so, but couldn't confirm that off the top of my head.

Comment: Won't that include empty directories?

Comment: Empty directories have `.` and `..` entries at least. Actually, I'm not sure how that plays together with the `SKIP_DOTS` directive. But in general, I think directories always have children, even if they're empty.

Comment: This seems to be confirmed by the documentation for [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator::hasChildren`](http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.haschildren.php): "Returns whether the current entry is a directory, but not '.' or '..'"